# Filtering with search-index

Tags: javascript, node.js, search, full-text-search, leveldb

I want to implement a full-text-search for *.epub-Files. Therefore I forked the *epub-full-text-search* module (https://github.com/friedolinfoerder/epub-full-text-search).
I will have many ebooks to search through, so I want to have a way to only search in a specific ebook one at a time.

How could I do this with search-index. I coded a solution which allows to search in the fields *filename* (the unique filename of the epub) and *body* (the content of the chapters), but this doesn't feel like it's the right way to do this and the performance is also not ideal.

Here is an example how I do the search with [search-index](https://github.com/fergiemcdowall/search-index):

```
searchIndex.search({
    query: [{
        AND: [
            {body: ['epub']},
            {filename: ['accessible_epub_3']}
        ]
    }]
});
```

Is there a better way to do this. Maybe with buckets, categories and filters?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Search-index, which epub-full-text-search is based on, gives one search result back for each document/item that has a match for any given query. My guess is that you would like to know where in the epub-file you get a hit. If a certain paragraph is a good enough search result item, I would index paragraphs. Each paragraph would have a unique book-key as a filter, and maybe a reference to where it is in the epub-file (page/percentage/etc).

Disclaimer: I'm working on the search-index project.

Comment: How is it going, @friedi ? Have you had any progress?